# Push Notification - Acumatica/Amazon

Tags: notifications, push, acumatica

Is it possible to send an information/update about availability Stock Item to e.g. Amazon using Push Notification. Have any of you tried something similar?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to do it with an IPushNotificationSender implementation. Using this you should be able to get any custom logic you need to directly engage whatever endpoint you need.
https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/(W(10))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=b1486a5a-a4b4-430d-7cc3-3395ec81e5aa